# Using MTOM File transfer with PHP SOAP Web Service library

Tags: php, rest, soap, mtom

We need to transfer file from one server to another using PHP SOAP or REST web service. We are considering MTOM for this. Any readily available php library for this?

Comment: Perhaps google can help you -- http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/08/19/send-binary-in-soap-with-wsfphp-132/

Comment: WSF/PHP library does not seem to be developed anymore. It was last updated in 2010 as per github listing